# sys.tables vs COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a variable `@tableName (NVARCHAR(255))` that is name of a table. I'm trying to perform an action if data exists in the the table.

There are two ways to check this.

Method #1 (bulky)

```
DECLARE @rowsInTable BIGINT
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cmd = 'SELECT @rowsInTable = COUNT_BIG(*) from '+ @tableName
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@rowsInTable INT OUTPUT', @rowsInTable OUTPUT

IF (@rowsInTable > 0)
PRINT 'Do something'
```

Method #2 (clean)

```
IF( EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = @tableName))
PRINT 'Do something'
```

- Are methods #1 and #2 doing the exact same thing?
- Is it safe to use method #2? Can there be case when data exists is `@tableName` but method #2 would return false?
- Is there a way I can make method #1 shorter? Or is there any third clean way to achieve this?

Comment: The second one doesn't `PRINT 'Do something'` if the table isn't empty. It does so when it merely exists. It could be empty though. (But for a temporary table you have to look up the catalog of the `tempdb` database. So unless that's your active database, you need to query `tempdb.sys.tables`. And the table name might actually differ.)

Comment: @stikybit the table isn't a temporary table. It's just a normal table with value

Comment: Edited Name to table to avoid ambiguity

Comment: Method #2 **only** checks to see if that**table exists** - it doesn't tell you whether it contains any data or not. So ***NO*** - #1 and #2 are **NOT** doing the same thing at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method #1 can be optimized. Used of `COUNT_BIG` can be avoided. Have a look into below query.

```
DECLARE @dataExists int
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cmd = 'SELECT @dataExists = case when Exists(Select 1 from '+ @tableName+') then 1 else 0 end'
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@dataExists INT OUTPUT', @dataExists OUTPUT

IF (@dataExists > 0)
PRINT 'Do something'
```

Comment: I think using  Select TOP 1 1 will further improve the performance??

`SET @cmd = 'SELECT @dataExists = case when Exists(Select TOP 1 1 from '+ @tableName+') then 1 else 0 end'`

Comment: @RahulSingh . . . `TOP` does not improve the results of `EXIST` queries; it is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation on SRKs answer, which is a little simpler to code:

```
SET @cmd = 'SELECT TOP 1 @dataExists = 1 FROM @tablename';
SET @cmd = REPLACE(@cmd, '@tablename', @tablename);

EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@dataExists INT OUTPUT', @dataExists OUTPUT
```

This actually returns `NULL` if the table is empty, but that is fine for the comparison.

Note:  I recommend using `QUOTENAME(@tablename)` for inserting the table name.  However, you may intend that your code accept multi-part table names so I didn't include it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table has a clustered index (index_id=1) you could use the sys.dm_db_partition_stats view which contains 'row_count' column.  Something like this

```
declare 
  @tableName        nvarchar(255)='dbo.users';

if exists (select * 
           from sys.dm_db_partition_stats
           where object_id=object_id(@tableName)
                 and index_id=1
                 and row_count>0)
    print('do something');
else
    print('no rows');
```